# what is the difference between framebuffer and x-server?

Tags: framebuffer, xserver

In Linux, always there is a driver node called "fbx" and it's used to render the image data in memory to the screen. In my opinion, x-server render the display through framerbuffer. Is that right? If not, what is the relation between them? I have googled a lot but I still can't find a satisfying answer.

Comment: Yes, x-server render the display through framebuffer but you have to be careful while applying any settings to fb0/1/2/3/4. Do you have a genuine problem or do you  want concept clarity?

Comment: I have used minigui years ago and it control fb without x-server. As a result, the question of x-server's mechanism came from my mind. anyway, thx a lot:)